# SharePoint SPFieldType.Integer issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, c#-3.0, rendering, fieldtype

I have to render dynamically  sharepoint fields of type `SPFieldType.Integer`,
`SPFieldType.Boolean`, `SPFieldType.DateTime`, `SPFieldTYpe.Guid`, `SPFieldTYpe.Counter`, `SPFieldType.Currency`, and `SPFieldType.Number` by code behind in C# .net

I still have Integer and Guid to render them.. but am facing some problems..
For now i will go with Integer...
Has anyone any clue how to render it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the SPFieldInteger doesnt have any fieldRenderingControl...it is rendered as number ,thus it is generated as SPFieldNumber